# Leaflet omnivore + clustering markers + filtering marker cluster group

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I try to make a map with mapbox and omnivore plugin of Leafet in order to search a data with the tutorial. I don't know how integrate this code from omnivore plugin in my case. I use for my datas a geojson url `$.getJSON`, clustering markers with MarkerCluster of Leaflet.

Thank you for your response.

Best regards.

Sandrine

EDIT

I try to filter marker cluster group with Mapbox js tool.

It works very well but I would like to insert this feature to my project. But I don't know how to make with the other features : omnivore plugin, search the data, displaying the popup, marker cluster group.  Could you help me ?

My js Fiddle "filtering marker cluster group" : https://jsfiddle.net/sduermael78/rgoxpxwq/4/

My project : https://jsfiddle.net/sduermael78/1uuubmwb/42/

Comment: Thank you for having shared your code in JSFiddle, it does help in providing support. Please note that with SO, the first step is to pinpoint your issue to decrease your code and share it in your question body, making a "[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)". More details on the [asking help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). JSFiddle is an additional bonus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently load your data through both jQuery `$.getJSON` and directly from your mapbox account.

Then if my understanding is correct, you would like to replace these methods by using [leaflet-omnivore](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore) plugin?

Direct replacement is quite straight forward, as you could directly use:

```js
var geojsonLayer = omnivore.geojson("filePath", null, L.mapbox.featureLayer());
geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
```

Now it becomes slightly more complicated when you want to cluster your markers (using Leaflet.markercluster plugin in your case). But it is similar to `$.getJSON` since both perform an asynchronous AJAX request, and you have to make the conversion in a callback.

With leaflet-omnivore, you use the [`.on("ready", callback)`](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore#async--events) syntax:

```js
var geojsonLayer = omnivore.geojson("filePath", null, L.mapbox.featureLayer())
  .on("ready", function() {
    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
    markers.addLayer(geojsonLayer);
    markers.addTo(mymap);
  });
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1uuubmwb/39/

---

**EDIT**

OK I missed your part where you "want to search the data" as done in the tutorial from mapbox you point to.

In your case it is more complicated as you want to cluster your markers, so you do not directly have your mapbox feature layer, but a marker cluster group.

A workaround would be to replace the content of that cluster group everytime you change the filtering condition on your `geojsonLayer` mapbox feature layer:

```js
// this will "hide" markers that do not match the filter.
geojsonLayer.setFilter(showCode);

// replace the content of marker cluster group.
markers.clearLayers();
markers.addLayer(geojsonLayer);
```

Then for your popup, you have to create it and bind it manually, as mapbox feature layer needs your GeoJSON data to use the `title` attribute (if so, it automatically uses that info to fill the popup / "tooltip" content):

```js
function attachPopups() {
  // Create popups.
    geojsonLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
      var props = layer.feature.properties;

      layer.bindPopup(
        "<b>Code unité&nbsp;:</b> " + props.CODE_UNITE + "<br />" +
        "<b>Adresse web&nbsp;:</b> <a href='" + props.ADRESSE_WEB + "' target='_blank'>" + props.ADRESSE_WEB + "</a>"
      );
    });
}
```

Unfortunately, it looks like `.setFilter()` removes that popup, so you would need to call this `attachPopups()` function after every `setFilter`.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1uuubmwb/40/

Comment: I would like to use leaflet-omnivore plugin in order to search a data from geojson with url.

Comment: How to display the popup from geojson with url in these new case ? layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.CODE);

Comment: I edited the above answer. Next time, please try to decouple your questions, so that people can answer to individual issues…

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. It works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. In fact, I would like to use leaflet-omnivore plugin in order to search a data from geojson with url.
The tutorial is : https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/filtering/
"Use setFilter as a fast search to filter out markers based on a user query".

How to display the popup from geojson with url in these new case ? `layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.CODE);`

Can I use all this features to build my map (search on markers, clustering markers...) ?

Comment: You should rather **edit** your question (there is a grey link below your question's tags) instead of adding an "answer". In fact, for your case, it sounds like it should even be a new question…

Comment: I am a beginner in this forum. Thank you for your advices.