# Leaflet markercluster division by filter layer control

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, markerclusterer

Based on this example:

http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/filter/filter.html

I developed my own map, but there is the problem with marker clustering.

I used this example to solve it:

[Leaflet omnivore + clustering markers + filtering marker cluster group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38702679/leaflet-omnivore-clustering-markers-filtering-marker-cluster-group)

And now my code looks as follows:

```
     $.getJSON(url, function(data) {

      var clusters = L.markerClusterGroup();
     //Initial Setup  with layer Verified No
     var mdu = L.geoJson(data, {

       pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            color:'black',
            fillColor:  'black',
            fillOpacity: 1,
            radius: 8
        })
       },  
       onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer._leaflet_id = feature.properties.Owner;
            var popupContent = "<p><h2>" +
                feature.properties.Owner + "</h2><font color='red'><h3>Status:</font> " +
                feature.properties.Status + "</h3><b> NBU ID:</b> " +
                feature.properties.NBU + "</br><b> Ticket ID:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Ticket_ID + "</br><b> Address (street):</b> " +
                feature.properties.Address + "</br><b> Address (postcode):</b> " +
                feature.properties.Postcode + "</br><b> Asbestos report:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Asbestos_rep + "</br><font color='blue'><b>Planner</b>:</font> " +
                feature.properties.Planner + "</br><font color='blue'><b>Surveyor</b>:</font> " +
                feature.properties.Surveyor + "</br></h2><b>Units provisional:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Client_Home_Count + "</br></h2><b> Post survey units:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count + "</br> <b>STATS (applied):</b> " +
                feature.properties.STATS_Applied_for_date + "</br> <b>STATS (completed):</b> " +
                feature.properties.STATS_compleeted + "</br> <b>VM issue date:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Date_issued_from_VM + "</br> <b>QC date:</b> " +
                feature.properties.ACTUAL_Internal_QC_Date + "</br> <b>VM ECD date:</b> " +
                feature.properties.VM_ECD_date + "</br><b>General notes:</b> " +
                feature.properties.General_notes + "</br>" +
                '</br><center><a href="'+ feature.properties.Directory +'" target="_blank">Local directory</a></center></p>' +
                '<center><font color="red"><a href="'+ feature.properties.Sharepoint +'" target="_blank">Sharepoint</a></font></center></p>';                   
            if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
                    popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
                }
            layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
            layer.addTo(clusters);
    },
    filter: function(feature, layer) {   
         return (feature.properties.Type =="MDU");
    },

}).addTo(map);  
map.addLayer(clusters);

   //mdu.addData(data);


    /// END Initial Setup

//Using a Layer Group to add/ remove data from the map.
var myData =  L.layerGroup([]);
    myData.addLayer(mdu);
    myData.addTo(map); 


//If Radio Button one is clicked.  
document.getElementById("radioOne").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
theExpression = 'feature.properties.Status == "Issued" ';
console.log(theExpression); 

    myData.clearLayers();
    map.removeLayer(myData);

    mdu = L.geoJson(data, {

        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                color:'black',
                fillColor:  'red',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                radius: 8
            })
        },  
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Owner);
        },
        filter: function(feature, layer) {   
             return (feature.properties.Type =="MDU") && (feature.properties.Status == "Issued" );
        },

    });
    map.addLayer(clusters);
    /*
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
           mdu.addData(data);
    });
    */

    myData.addLayer(mdu);
    myData.addTo(map);;
});



       //If Radio button two is clicked.
       document.getElementById("radioTwo").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
       theExpression = 'feature.properties.Status == "Completed_and_invoiced" ';    
        console.log(theExpression);
    map.removeLayer(myData);
    myData.clearLayers();

    mdu = L.geoJson(null, {

        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                color:'black',
                fillColor:  'green',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                radius: 8
            })
        },  
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Owner);
        },
        filter: function(feature, layer) {   
             return(feature.properties.Type =="MDU")&&(feature.properties.Status == "Completed_and_invoiced" );
        },

    });

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
           mdu.addData(data);
    });

    myData.addLayer(mdu);
    myData.addTo(map);
});

//If Survey is clicked.
document.getElementById("Survey").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
theExpression = 'feature.properties.Status == "Survey_to_arrange" ';    
console.log(theExpression);
    map.removeLayer(myData);
    myData.clearLayers();

    mdu = L.geoJson(null, {

        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                color:'black',
                fillColor:  'yellow',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                radius: 8
            })
        },  
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Owner);
        },
        filter: function(feature, layer) {   
             return(feature.properties.Type =="MDU")&&(feature.properties.Status == "Survey_to_arrange" );
        },

    });

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
           mdu.addData(data);
    });

    myData.addLayer(mdu);
    myData.addTo(map);
});


     //If On-Hold is clicked.
     document.getElementById("On-hold").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    //theExpression = 'feature.properties.Status == "Do_not_design" ';  
    //console.log(theExpression);
    map.removeLayer(myData);
    myData.clearLayers();

    mdu = L.geoJson(null, {

        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                color:'black',
                fillColor:  'orange',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                radius: 8
            })
        },  
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Owner);
        },
        filter: function(feature, layer) {   
             return(feature.properties.Type =="MDU")&&(feature.properties.Status == "Do_not_design" 
   );
        },

    });

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
           mdu.addData(data);
    });

    myData.addLayer(mdu);
    myData.addTo(map);
});

//If Upoloaded is clicked.
document.getElementById("Uploaded").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
//theExpression = 'feature.properties.Status == "Design_uploaded" ';    
//console.log(theExpression);
    map.removeLayer(myData);
    myData.clearLayers();

    mdu = L.geoJson(null, {

        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                color:'black',
                fillColor:  'purple',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                radius: 8
            })
        },  
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Owner);
        },
        filter: function(feature, layer) {   
             return(feature.properties.Type =="MDU")&&(feature.properties.Status == 
     "Design_uploaded" );
        },

    });

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
           mdu.addData(data);
    });

    myData.addLayer(mdu);
    myData.addTo(map);
     });

    //If Inactive is clicked.
   document.getElementById("Inactive").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
//theExpression = 'feature.properties.Status == "?" ';  
//console.log(theExpression);
    map.removeLayer(myData);
    myData.clearLayers();

    mdu = L.geoJson(null, {

        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                color:'black',
                fillColor:  'grey',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                radius: 8
            })
        },  
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Owner);
        },
        filter: function(feature, layer) {   
             return(feature.properties.Type =="MDU")&&(feature.properties.Status == "?" );
        },

    });

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
           mdu.addData(data);
    });

    myData.addLayer(mdu);
    myData.addTo(map);
});

//If All is clicked.
document.getElementById("All").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
//theExpression = 'feature.properties.Type == "MDU" ';  
//console.log(theExpression);
    map.removeLayer(myData);
    myData.clearLayers();

    mdu = L.geoJson(data, {

        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                color:'black',
                fillColor:  'black',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                radius: 8
            })
        },  
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Owner);
        },
        filter: function(feature, layer) {   
             return(feature.properties.Type =="MDU");
        },

    });

    /*
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
           mdu.addData(data);
    });
    */

    myData.addLayer(mdu);
    myData.addTo(map);
 });
```

Despite filter option the amount of marker remains the same. As it worst, the markers from different sublayers (switched off) are populated too.

The console says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_targets' of null
>       at e.removeInteractiveTarget (leaflet.js:6)
>       at e._removePath (leaflet.js:8)
>       at e.onRemove (leaflet.js:7)
>       at e.removeLayer (leaflet.js:6)
>       at e.removeLayer (leaflet.js:7)
>       at e.removeLayer (leaflet.js:7)
>       at leaflet.markercluster.js:1
>       at e._recursively (leaflet.markercluster.js:1)
>       at e._recursivelyRemoveChildrenFromMap (leaflet.markercluster.js:1)
>       at leaflet.markercluster.js:1

Could you help me solve it? How can I divide the markercluster layer between the geoJSON layer filtered?

Any help cordially appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Try to create a own markercluster layer for each marker type you want. You can add a layer to a group in `onEachFeature`, but don't add the geojson layer to a group / map

Comment: Could you show me more or less how to do that? I have been trying 3 days to achieve sth reasonable

Comment: Can you pls explain what you want to achieve? Do you want that you have for the different markers (grouped by property) a own clusterlayer or do you want, that only the selected (from radio button) markers visible? And I don't understand your images, what does them mean?

Comment: As per to my code I want to divide the markerclusters between the layers filtered. As you can see, my markercluster ferers to the mdu layer, the same as the filter, which subtles to the mdu layer either. I cannot split them and the console returns an error. Shall I use markercluster subgroup?  If so, I have to create separate markercluster group for each layer filtered (as you told me above), but I don't know how to manage with it

Comment: Try following: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/2mp7tqnx/

Comment: Hi mate, I tried and very appreciate your help. Unfortunately there is no result, that would make me happy. In the other hand it's still something, as I have got all layers filered in one peace, as follows:
https://imgur.com/baEWSCP

Comment: Hi,

I forgot to add a HTML section. Now it works :) Thank you for your help.